# How can I restrict Facebook scripts?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I'm running Firefox with NoScript. How can I restrict Facebook scripts to run only when I visit the site and not on 3rd party web sites like say, engadget?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [NoScript's ABE](http://noscript.net/abe):

```
# facebook.com containment rule
# This rule allows Facebook scripts objects and frames to be included only
# from Facebook pages
Site .facebook.com .fbcdn.net
Accept from .facebook.com .fbcdn.net
Deny INCLUSION(SCRIPT, OBJ, SUBDOC)
```

Answer (score 4):

Go the lazy route and install [Facebook Blocker](http://webgraph.com/resources/facebookblocker/).

Comment: Haven't tried this extension, however I wanted a more generic blocker as opposed to just blocking facebook on 3rd party sites.

Answer (score 2):

With Adblock Plus, I use these two rules:

```
facebook.com^$third-party
fbcdn.net^$domain=~facebook.com
```

Comment: Not quite the answer I was looking for, but since I use ad block plus as well, this works. Thanks!